# Why does Twilio call forwarding operate differently than carrier call forwarding?

Tags: twilio, forwarding

From what I understand, there is a difference between how Twilio handles call forwarding and how the telcom carriers do it.

In the first situation, for standard carrier forwarding, say A calls B.  The call gets forwarded to C if either B doesn't answer (conditional call forwarding) or they've set up to always forward (unconditional call forwarding).  In other words, the call is routed from the red line to the purple.  This is done on the carrier side (B's phone does not even need to be on for this to work).

[image: Carrier call forwarding vs. Twilio]

However, in the case with Twilio, if A is already talking to Twilio (purple path) and application logic decides it is OK to connect A to C (same final result as with the first situation), it does this by passing through Twilio (green path).  Twilio calls this Call Forwarding even though it does not behave the same way as before.  In this case, there is a middleman in the picture (Twilio), and [Twilio also charges you for both the ingoing and outgoing legs](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223132367-How-Much-am-I-Charged-for-Call-Forwarding-with-Twilio-).

Is it possible for Twilio to forward the call such that it just takes the blue path, and connects A to C directly?  Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Twilio Programmable Voice uses Twilio Markup Language (TwiML) to control the call flow. If you call your Twilio number and want to forward that call to an end-point off Twilio, Twilio still remains in the signaling and media path, which allows you to remain in control of the call, which is the key part of why that call path is the way it is.

There is no way to remove Twilio from this call flow, as Programmable Voice depends on Twilio remaining in the call path.

[Setting Up Call Forwarding](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223179908-Setting-Up-Call-Forwarding)